# podio api: get the latest revision date of a single field or an app

Tags: node.js, version-control, podio

Context: I'm building a Node app to backup our Podio apps' calculation fields via the Podio API; they are saved as flat files and version controlled with Git. We want to have the possibility to edit the text files locally, commit and then push back the modified files.

I've been inspecting the object's keys returned but can't find a way to determine the latest revision date for the app (not the item).

- I came across the 'current_revision' when polling the app (/app/{app_id}/) but can't figure out how to use a revision number for an app.
- I also noted (very hopeful) the wording "This method will always return the latest revision of the app definition." on the page https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications/get-app-22349 but I couldn't find any other mention of this… Can I get to the date via some meta information on an app's revisions?

Ideally, I would like to compare the last modification date of a local file (fs.stat) with the last revision date from the app (or from the app's field).

Any insights appreciated; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Podio API does not currently provide a way to access additional information regarding App revision history.  One approach that you might try is to utilize Podio's [Webhooks](https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks), which can be setup to trigger whenever an app is updated (`app.update`).  Similarly, when an App template is modified, a [notification](https://developers.podio.com/doc/notifications) w/ timestamp is generated, which you can subscribe to.

I have generated a feature request with the API team regarding a means to access additional revision history for an App, and have been informed that this limitation of the API is on their radar.

Thanks for your question, and interest in developing with Podio.  Happy coding!